# How to add css for properties in React Material UI

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-router, react-redux, material-ui

Here I have used `<AppBar/>` with properties like `iconElementRight`. On checking in browser I can see `iconElementRight` as separate `div`. I need to add margin to the `iconElementRight`. Thanks...

```
<div>
  <AppBar
    title="Component Catalog"
    iconElementRight={<img src={require('../../assets/images/logo-footer.png')} alt="logo" />}
    style={{ border: '1px solid black' }}
  />
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`Material-ui AppBar`](http://www.material-ui.com/#/components/app-bar) has a prop called `iconStyleRight` which overrides the inline styles of element on right side, you could use it like

```
<div >
   <AppBar title="Component Catalog" 
        iconElementRight = {<img src={require('../../assets/images/logo-footer.png')} alt="logo"/>}
        iconStyleRight={{ margin: '10px' }}
        style={{border:'1px solid black'}}
        />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `iconStyleRight` or `iconClassNameRight` prop of AppBar to add your own style to the icon div.

You can refer to the properties of [Material AppBar](http://www.material-ui.com/#/components/app-bar)